# Ball rolling instead of bouncing on paddle in Brick breaken game

Tags: kivy

I am developing a brick-breaking game in Kivy and I am experiencing an issue where the ball sometimes rolls horizontally on the paddle instead of bouncing off of it. I have implemented collision detection using the collide_widget() method. I don't know the cause of this problem.
Here is the part of the code concerned:( 'raquette' is the paddle. 'widget' is a ball)

```
# test si la balle touche le paddle
                if self.raquette.pos[1] - self.raquette.height <= widget.y <= \
                        self.raquette.pos[1] + self.raquette.height:
                    if widget.collide_widget(self.raquette):
                        if self.son_raquette:
                            self.son_raquette.play()
                        widget.velocity_y *= -1
```

I added a condition to make sure that the ball doesn't bounce on the side of the padlle, but this is obviously not the cause of my problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the phenomenon is produced when the collision of the ball with the paddle was detected in the paddle and not on its surface... To solve this problem, I added a test:

```
if self.ball.collide_widget(self.paddle):
    if self.ball.y < self.paddle.y + self.paddle.height:
        self.ball.y = self.paddle.y + self.paddle.height + 1
                        self.ball.velocity_y *= -1
```